# Failed to run script function from Custom Actions

Tags: installshield, installscript

I implemented an installscript file of my own that will allow the installer to register dll's. I combined this with a custom action to actually run the function I created. I had to make this script because the dlls were failing to register with setting the property to self register. So I am stuck on how to resolve this problem with the custom action failing so that I can test my script. 
Below is my script:

```
#include "Ifx.h"

export prototype RegisterComponents(HWND);

function RegisterComponents(hMSI)

STRING sRunStr;

begin

sRunStr = WINSYSDIR ^ "regsvr32.exe";

LongPathToQuote(sRunStr, TRUE);

//change the directory to target directory
ChangeDirectory(TARGETDIR);

//register dll
if(LaunchAppAndWait(sRunStr, "/s " + 
"C:\NCRUniEmulatorService\NCRUniEmulatorSO.dll", 
WAIT)) < 0) then
MessageBox("NCRUniEmulatorSO.dll", SEVERE);
else
endif;

end;
```

Below is my custom actions:

FunctionName: RegisterComponents

Return Processing: Synchronous

In-Script Execution: Deferred Execution

Install Exec Sequence: After PublishProduct

All other sequence settings are set to Absent from sequence.

**log file**

> InstallShield 14:17:18: Invoking script function RegisterComponents
>   InstallShield 14:17:18: Failed to run script function, error
>   0x80020006 InstallShield 14:17:18: CallScriptFunctionFromMsiCA() ends,
>   result 0x643 CustomAction RegisterComponents returned actual error
>   code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking

Comment: Did you manage to use the COM Extract?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an MSI project? [I would not use self-registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129816/msi-register-dll-self-registration-considered-harmful/6141538#6141538), instead enable COM Extract at Build in the property page for the component in question:

[image: COM Extract at build]

If this extraction does not work, then you might have dependencies that are not met for the file to load. For example a missing resource dll or something like that. The extraction process for "COM Extract at Build" will populate a number of MSI-specific COM tables that take care of all COM registration details for you (including rollback support).

***InstallShield Self-Registration***: Additionally you can enable self-registration for a file in Installshield and not run via custom action code at all. I think it is in the property page for each file.