# Why does Regsvr32 work on one machine but not the other

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, regsvr32, advanced-installer

When I go to register a dll as an admin on my machine it works fine:

Regsvr32 C:\nameofdll.dll

However when I run it on another machine it fails.
Why is that?

Comment: The error can be caused due to the architecture of the machine, probably one of them is running in x86 and the other one in x64. I would recommend you this post to try to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

> ***Error codes***: [Error codes can be looked up using one of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573312/129130).

---

***[Regsvr32.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html) - Admin Rights Required***: As far as I know self-registration requires admin rights since it registers the DLL per-machine - or in other words in the **`HKLM`** / **`HKCR`** sections of the registry (**`HKCR`** is a view into a part of **`HKLM`** and a merge from sections of **`HKCU`** - in other words it is an "**emergent view**" from both **`HKCU`** and **`HKLM`**). Now I see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/400558/how-can-i-regsvr32-my-controls-at-a-user-hkey-current-user-level) which seems to indicate that there are ways to register COM servers per user? It **doesn't** work for my test OCX files using [this method](https://superuser.com/a/405275/11906). I did not try [the custom registration EXE from codeproject](https://superuser.com/a/477032/11906).

***MSI - Per-User COM Registration***: Windows Installer - on the other hand - is able to install COM servers per-user for setups that install per-user. Per-user setups are bad for a number of reasons (serviceability, upgrading, patching, various limitations), but that is another story. If you [enable Installshield's **COM Extract On Build** as I showed in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571564/129130), the COM data is added to your MSI in a way that ensures that the COM server can be registered per-user - if the setup is installed per-user, or per-machine if the setup is installed per-machine. ***This is the standard way to register COM files using Windows Installer***.

***Bitness***: Other problem causes are possible, such as the mentioned "bitness" of the COM server. I have encountered very few x64 COM servers, but they are problematic to deal with using WiX for example. As far as I know the WiX 3.11 release does not support x64 COM servers for extraction. Similar problems could exist in Installshield - I don't know.

[Support Page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages): On a 64-bit version of Windows operating system, there are two versions of the **`Regsv32.exe`** file:

- The 64-bit version is **`%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe`**
- The 32-bit version is **`%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe`**

***Lacking Dependencies***: Self-registration can also fail if there are lacking dependencies for the file in question. You can use a tool such as dependency walker to check, or you can monitor with procmon or [**any number of scanner tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939079/which-winform-project-files-should-be-packed-up-into-the-installer/51940598#51940598) (have a quick skim). Note that it is also possible that you lack a "language dll" for the COM server. For example: `MyApp-English.dll`. Such a file should be located next to your main COM server file `MyApp.dll` or `MyApp.ocx` to allow registration to work correctly.

***Oddities***: Numerous other problems can be seen. Ranging from `licensing issues`, `COM interoperability` with .NET (regasm.exe), interference from weird `security policies`, `security software interference` - anti virus etc... To any number of `other specific and rare factors`.

> ***Warning***: I have seen self-registration perform illegal actions and change core system values during the self-registration process - without any warning or explanation. Hence the recommendation to [avoid
>   self-registration during deployment whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129816/msi-register-dll-self-registration-considered-harmful/6141538#6141538).