# msiexec returns negative number

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer

I am getting an odd return code from msiexec when installing an MSI. Namely, `-2147021886`. I THINK I remember reading somewhere that this is some sort of format or encoding issue, but I can't find the reference. I also found a microsoft page that talks about PS2.o having issues with negative return codes, but this is happening in PS5.0.

Comment: `-2147021886` is `0x80070BC2`, which according to [this page](http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/archive/windows_update_codes.htm) means `ErrorControlRebootRequired`.

Comment: @Jonathon, where did you find that? My Google-Fu has only ever gotten me variations on this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/error-codes). Now I guess I need to try to figure out which ones I may encounter, because that is a monstrous list.

Comment: Added a site that might help with things like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***"The Magic Number Database"***: I recently discovered [**magnumdb.com**](https://www.magnumdb.com) ([`cleared virustotal 30-9-2018`](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/7749059d592c355b437038aea869b3953777d8c0d201ee17723148a10c511dea/detection)) in a tweet
>   from [Remko Weijnen](https://twitter.com/RemkoWeijnen/status/1042416626929491968). **`"The Magic Number Database"`** is
>   apparently maintained by [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier).
>
> ***Looking up your error code:*** https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=-2147021886
>
> `1    ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED   Int32   -2147021886 %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\shared\winerror.h(11960,0)`

---

***Other Approaches***: Including a couple of other options for similar situations.

1. ***Visual Studio (2017)***: Menu choice: **`Tools => Error Lookup`**. This Visual Studio tool (**`errlook.exe`**) can be found in the **`"Tools" folder`** of your Visual Studio installation. **N.B! Localized messages!** (internationalized).

   [image: errlook.exe]
2. ***cmd.exe***: Via the command line, the **`net command`** can normally be used to look up error codes: **`net helpmsg errorcode`**. See blog link below for limitations.
3. ***certutil.exe***: Try it via cmd.exe: **`certutil.exe /error errorcode`**. Not sure if this is available in a clean install, but with Visual Studio it should be already available. **Appears very good! Localized messages**.
4. ***Err.exe***: An old tool from the Exchange team. Dated now. See blog link below - in the comments. [Needs download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985). **English messages, non-localized**.

And in C++ the [**`FormatMessage`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinBase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) call. And just mentioning the **`winerror.h`** and **`ntstatus.h`** files. [**`Retrieving the Last-Error Code`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/retrieving-the-last-error-code). And a [**`Powershell blog`**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/saudm/2015/01/19/enumerating-status-message-strings-in-powershell/).

---

***calc.exe***: And obviously use the new [Windows 10 **`calc.exe`**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-calculator/9wzdncrfhvn5) in "**Programmer Mode**" to convert between hex / dec and all kinds of other tasks:

[image: calc.exe]

---

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170919-00/?p=97046

Comment: it's not apparent, it's a reality :-)

Comment: "*Simon says...*" :-). Thanks for verifying that. The reality, Simon, is that your site is a gem when I don't have access to my normal toolbox and Visual Studio. Thanks! :-).