# Windows installer MSI for domain users

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2019

We have created the msi file using windows installer project in visual studio 2019 we have a requirement that end user could install the msi

End users will be under Active directory so user will install our msi in their domains

If user installs the msi UAC message is displayed prompting admin password

How to create msi using windows installer project in visual studio 2019 or anyother installer have this option to install without UAC

We tried using changing msi location to localAppData of the corresponding domain that time also UAC is displayed

Comment: I don't use this distribution mechanism, but you can [check the links here in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798434/129130). Also make a proper log file to see what is going on. There are many restrictions on making a package that does not require admin rights. [Here is an answer on per-user setups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399651/129130) and [Advanced Installer: Single Package Authoring](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/single-package.html). WiX allows more flexibility for the MSI - VSInstaller MSIs may have limitations by design that affect AD deployment.