# What does a <class> element do under <File> in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

I'm trying to understand what Class means inside a File element and I can't find anything using google. The reason that I need to understand this is that I'm converting a WiX installer to InstallShield. According the the WiX docs Classes are COM components but I don't think that applies here (and if it does then I have a whole other question about how to use COM components in InstallShield, but I'll skip that question for now. Here's the code. Can someone please tell me what this is doing?

```
<File Id="pg_audio_sink.ax" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.DirectShow)\pg_audio_sink\Release\pg_audio_sink.ax">
      <Class Id="{7E4D071A-50B7-42D8-ADFE-B0C3715422B9}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="AAC Encoder" ThreadingModel="both" />
      <Class Id="{2A67EDA3-7AE8-494E-808C-60C1E2C992C1}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Settings" ThreadingModel="both" />
      <Class Id="{AF94923E-31C7-483A-A2EA-57D86BF26AD7}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="Settings" ThreadingModel="both" />
</File>
```

Comment: When looking at the file with dependency walker or some other tool to view exported functions, do you see `DllRegisterServer`? Installshield should be able to extract COM registration data for COM files by setting the component flag "[COM Extract at Build...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571564/129130)", but I am not sure this type of file can be registered in the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please tell me what this is doing?

This `File` element is to register `pg_audio_sink.ax`, which is DirectShow Filter.
See also:
[How to Register DirectShow Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/how-to-register-directshow-filters)
[How to Implement IUnknown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/how-to-implement-iunknown)

Your code will create 3 registry key, and register `pg_audio_sink.ax` as COM server.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E4D071A-50B7-42D8-ADFE-B0C3715422B9}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{2A67EDA3-7AE8-494E-808C-60C1E2C992C1}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{AF94923E-31C7-483A-A2EA-57D86BF26AD7}
```

DirectShow is based on COM.
So I think `Class` element in your code is for COM component.