# Extract COM Data from EXE Server

Tags: com, wix

Hi I am trying to Extract the registration entries I need from my EXE so that I can register it using my wix setup.

I have tried using Regspy but i only get the error 'Can't Create Process', does anyone know another way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26304137/1073262 that uses a utility called RegSpyUI